# What is binding in PHP and MySQL? And what are the uses of it?

Tags: php, mysql, binding

I usually use mysql_query() to get data from mysql database. But some people use binding to set results. What is the different between then? In my view both give the same result. But i feel binding is bit complicated. Can anyone please what are the advantages of using bind? Thank you.

Comment: The difference is preventing SQL injection, and performance if you're repeating the same query several times with different data values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data binding offers enhanced protection from SQL injection attacks (sometimes referred to as SQLIA). SQL injections are malicious attempts to gain access to your database for reasons outside intended use. Use your imagination here. As a result, using `mysql_connect` is a really bad idea and the [library is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). For a more comprehensive overview, see [this article](http://codular.com/php-mysqli).

Binding is not as complicated as it seems if you break down a SQL query, it can very easily explained.

Take the following code in the old `mysql` library as an example:

```
mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO users (username, password, user_data) VALUES ('derek_jeter', 'password', 'additional_data')"
);
```

This code is vulnerable to SQLIA. With a library such as PDO, you just need to add an extra step to avoid the issue entirely. To achieve the same result in a safer library, you just need to translate the above code into the following:

```
$db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, user_data) VALUES (:username, :password, :additional_data)";

$db->execute(
    array("username" => "derek_jeter", "password" => "password", "additional_data" => "additional_data")
);
```

Binding sends the data to be inserted into MySQL separately from the query, and understands how to parse it for insertion without risking safety of the database. With the `execute` function, you just pass the array with keys corresponding to the placeholder data you defined in the `prepare` function.

Note: I'm using the word "function", but since the PDO library is actually an object you manipulate, the functions contained in the PDO class are technically referred to as "methods".

There's a bit more you'll need to do before you can just run queries in PDO (such as instantiating the PDO connection and class), but I'll refer you to [the docs which explain everything in great detail](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).

Also, [here's a tutorial I used when I first started using PDO and MySQLi](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338).